# Replace Java for loop with Stream API

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java-stream

*My code:*

```
Map<Integer, String> people = Map.of(
      1, "John", 2, "Michael", 3, "Bob", 4, "Liza", 5, "Anna"
 );

String[] names = new String[people.size];

for (int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
     names[i] = people.get(i);
}
```

I want to replace `for`-loop with something like:

```
Arrays.stream(people.forEach(person -> names[i] = persons.get(i)));
```

Comment: Does it have to be a stream? Can't you use `persons.values().toArray(new String[0])`?

Comment: @Ivar Yeah, sure, it have to be a stream. But thanks for suggested solution.

Comment: @DmitriyDmitruk It is suspicious that you do not accept Ivar's solution. What you really want to achieve? Ivar's solution is the most correct replacement of your code. Please read https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Alexander Are you sure it is `people` and not `responseItems` as originally posted? Not the best idea to make such changes to posted code IMO! Or did I miss some comment?

Comment: @user16320675 I've made a conclusion that these collections are the same, judging by the OP's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057221/replace-java-for-loop-with-stream-api/74057484#comment130757997_74057221) to the comment 
*Ivar*, where OP says that the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057221/replace-java-for-loop-with-stream-api/74057484#comment130757823_74057221) which *Ivar* has provided does **what expected**, but they want to use a Stream.

Comment: Can you clarify what `responseItems` is? Is it the `peaple` map mistakenly named like that, or a separate collection?

Comment: @Alexander  [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code): "*...  Code in questions should only be edited for formatting and readability ... **Don't:** Change the code logic or functionality ...*" ||| as it is now, most previous comments are incomplete/confusing/wrong (it is sure adding value to your answer ... but with a *sour taste*)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`IntStream.range()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) (or `rangeClosed()`) and [`Stream.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) to implement the same logic with Stream API:

```
Map<Integer, String> people = Map.of(
    1, "John", 2, "Michael", 3, "Bob", 4, "Liza", 5, "Anna"
);
        
String[] names = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
    .mapToObj(people::get)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

If the *keys* of the original map are not integers, or the map is represented by a plain `HashMap` which is incapable of maintaining the order, but you need to reflect the ordering of *keys* in the resulting array, then create a stream of entries and sort them by *key* as suggested by *@Holger*:

```
String[] names = people.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

In case if the order of elements is not important, then you can use [`Collection.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)):

```
String[] names = people.values().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: The `for` loop looks better, IMO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but the loop code has an off-by-one error. So don’t tell me that the loop was more readable when no-one spotted the error yet…

Comment: But maybe, `String[] names = people.entrySet().stream() .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).map(Map.Entry::getValue).toArray(String[]::new);` would be the even more reliable solution…

Comment: @Holger Good point, incorporated this solution into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```java
 Map<Integer, String> persons = new HashMap<>();
//Option one
    String[] names = persons.entrySet().stream().map(e-> e.getValue())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
    //Option two
            persons.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Just transform the map to list and then make it an Array, well, we use a stream  in the collection values or in the entrySet.

Comment: There’s no sense in collecting into a `List`, just to call `toArray` on it, as you can call `toArray` on the stream in the first place. Just use `toArray(String[]::new)` instead of `toArray(new String[0])`

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, String> people = Map.of(
    1, "John", 2, "Michael", 3, "Bob", 4, "Liza", 5, "Anna"
);

String[] unorderedNames = people.values().toArray(String[]::new);
String[] namesInTheSameOrder = people.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Instead of `entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)` you can use `values().stream()` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

***You can use the below approaches to get the desired results:***

***Here,***

- **Approach 1 :** Took the values from the map and converted into Array. *No sorting is considered here.*
- **Approach 2:** Took the `entrySet()` and sorted by the key of the map and converted the entryset into values using `map()` and then converted into Array. *Sorting is considered here.*

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> people = 
                Map.of(1, "John", 2, "Michael", 3, "Bob", 4, "Liza", 5, "Anna");

        //Approach 1 : Data without sorting
        String[] peopleNames = people.values().toArray(String[]::new);

        //Approach 2: Data with sorting by key of the map
        String[] peopleNamesSortedByKey = people.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue).toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

**Output::**

```
Bob Michael John Anna Liza // No sorting
John Michael Bob Liza Anna // Sorted by Key
```